# Dangers and concerns of exporting data while database is in use

Tags: sql-server-2008, export

Is there any danger or things to be concerned of when using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (Exporting only to flat file) from the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, while the DB is in use by live production systems?

I would think not, but my project manager(non programmer) is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be that you won't have proper data because there will be live transactions in your DB. Also it would put unnecessary load on the DB.

I would agree with your manager.